# Capturando dados de inputs do tipo "radio" e transformando em JSON

Tags: javascript, json, spring-boot, thymeleaf

(Esse projeto está sendo desenvolvido com Spring Boot + Thymeleaf) Eu tenho uma página html que vai funcionar como um questionário contendo mais ou menos 100 perguntas (o código abaixo é só um exemplo). Cada pergunta tem 4 inputs.

```
<div>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" th:name="${question.id}" th:data-correct="${question.correctOption}" value="a" /><span th:text="${question.optionA}"></span>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" th:name="${question.id}" th:data-correct="${question.correctOption}" value="b" /><span th:text="${question.optionB}"></span>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" th:name="${question.id}" th:data-correct="${question.correctOption}" value="c" /><span th:text="${question.optionC}"></span>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" th:name="${question.id}" th:data-correct="${question.correctOption}" value="d" /><span th:text="${question.optionD}"></span>
</div>
```

Eu quero pegar, via JavaScript (JQuery), todos os inputs que estão "checked" e armazená-los em um JSON e em seguida, mandar esse objeto para um controller via Ajax.

```
function getAllResults() {
var inputs = $('input:radio:checked');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    //inserir os dados em um objeto JSON 
}
```

A minha dúvida é (caso seja possível) , como armazenar os dados dentro do JSON?
Exemplo:

("answer" seria o atributo "value" e "correctOption" seria o atributo "th:data-correct")

```
[
  {"answer": c, "correctOption": b}
  {"answer": a, "correctOption": d}
  {"answer": d, "correctOption": a}
  {"answer": b, "correctOption": c}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `.push` de objetos com os valores em uma array.

No exemplo alterei alguns atributos para que se possa visualizar o resultado aqui no snippet:

```js
function getAllResults() {
   
   var respostas = []; // array onde serão guardados todos os resultados
   
   var inputs = $('input:radio:checked');
   
   for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      respostas.push({
         "answer" : inputs[i].value,
         "correctOption":  inputs[i].dataset.correct
      });
   }
   
   console.log(respostas);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   Marque uma opção
   <br>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" name="q1" data-correct="b" value="a" /><span th:text="${question.optionA}"></span>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" name="q1" data-correct="b" value="b" /><span th:text="${question.optionB}"></span>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" name="q1" data-correct="b" value="c" /><span th:text="${question.optionC}"></span>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" name="q1" data-correct="b" value="d" /><span th:text="${question.optionD}"></span>
</div>
<div>
   Marque uma opção
   <br>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" name="q2" data-correct="d" value="a" /><span th:text="${question.optionA}"></span>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" name="q2" data-correct="d" value="b" /><span th:text="${question.optionB}"></span>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" name="q2" data-correct="d" value="c" /><span th:text="${question.optionC}"></span>
    <input class="question-option" type="radio" name="q2" data-correct="d" value="d" /><span th:text="${question.optionD}"></span>
</div>
<button onclick="getAllResults()">Resultados</button>
```